# How can I reuse my JsonSerializerOptions in my Startup.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is a class that defines an instance of `JsonSerializerOptions`:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static JsonSerializerOptions Options
    {
        get
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
                PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All),
                NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString,
                ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Allow,
                UnknownTypeHandling = JsonUnknownTypeHandling.JsonNode,
                DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
            };
            options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
            return options;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in my `Startup.cs` I want to reuse this class:

```
var builder = services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
}).AddJsonOptions(options => new JsonOptions{
  // I can't set options.JsonSerializerOptions, because it's readonly.
});
```

Comment: Can you change `JsonHelper` to provide a method to set properties on an existing `JsonSerializerOptions`? (Then refactor the property to just use the method.)

Comment: That's a nice solution. I'll try that.

Comment: Unrelated tip: instead of typing `options.Converters.Add(...)` outside of the object initializer, you can achieve the same effect by typing this inside the object initializer: `Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() }`. This does not assign a new list to `Converters` like you may think (it has no setter after all), but calls the `.Add` method on `Converters`! With this approach, you may be able to convert the whole property into expression body.

Comment: Can you do this? `).AddJsonOptions(options => JsonHelper.Options);`